# Ubuntu Karmic Koala - Missing Package Manager

Tags: ubuntu

I dont seet the "Package Manager" under system administration. I only see the system monitor. How can I install this?

Answer (score 1):

It is called Synaptic. If this is removed in Karmic Koala (10.04) then you can install it yourself by using the "Ubuntu Software Centre" and searching for Synaptic.

Or from the command line do

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

The alternative is to just use "Ubuntu Software Centre" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a server, aptitude or apt is what most people use. The front end you are thinking of though, is likely synaptic , though if you run KDE it'll be kpackage kit

Comment: As this is a server site. You make a good point. Does anyone run server with a GUI and Synaptic for package management?